# How can I add Vertice Attributes to a Graph created using TupleList?

Tags: python, igraph

I have a list of document IDs:

```
10.1.1.100.1022 10.1.1.133.7112 10.1.1.52.4809
10.1.1.100.1037 10.1.1.111.3104 10.1.1.14.3331 10.1.1.102.1525 10.1.1.108.8376 10.1.1.102.3750 10.1.1.164.6517 10.1.1.103.5318 10.1.1.100.2602
10.1.1.100.1045 10.1.1.106.5713 10.1.1.14.3960 10.1.1.156.2724
10.1.1.100.1057 10.1.1.111.8464 10.1.1.105.6486 10.1.1.138.784 10.1.1.121.2733
10.1.1.100.1062 10.1.1.13.9919 10.1.1.12.787 10.1.1.33.4425 10.1.1.19.1677 10.1.1.88.3931
10.1.1.100.1098 10.1.1.55.8054 10.1.1.47.3891 10.1.1.47.7464 10.1.1.38.6745 10.1.1.52.168 10.1.1.41.1417
10.1.1.100.1132 10.1.1.116.4594 10.1.1.128.174
10.1.1.100.1153 10.1.1.38.3827 10.1.1.18.7575 10.1.1.56.3738 10.1.1.110.7560 10.1.1.101.9958 10.1.1.28.7411 10.1.1.18.2975
10.1.1.100.1164 10.1.1.39.9796 10.1.1.104.2119 10.1.1.8.7906 10.1.1.131.2434 10.1.1.78.8998 10.1.1.6.6222
10.1.1.100.1196 10.1.1.153.7628 10.1.1.100.8001 10.1.1.31.2802 10.1.1.19.3462 10.1.1.128.9154
```

The first column is the DOCID that is being cited by the following DOCs in the same row.

so for the first row - 10.1.1.133.7112 -> 10.1.1.100.1022 & 10.1.1.52.4809 -> 10.1.1.100.1022

I've created a graph using python-igraph TupleList. Here's the list:

> [('10.1.1.133.7112', '10.1.1.100.1022'), ('10.1.1.52.4809',
>   '10.1.1.100.1022'), ('10.1.1.111.3104', '10.1.1.100.1037'),
>   ('10.1.1.14.3331', '10.1.1.100.1037'), ('10.1.1.102.1525',
>   '10.1.1.100.1037'), ('10.1.1.108.8376', '10.1.1.100.1037'),
>   ('10.1.1.102.3750', '10.1.1.100.1037'), ('10.1.1.164.6517',
>   '10.1.1.100.1037'), ('10.1.1.103.5318', '10.1.1.100.1037'),
>   ('10.1.1.100.2602', '10.1.1.100.1037'), ('10.1.1.106.5713',
>   '10.1.1.100.1045'), ('10.1.1.14.3960', '10.1.1.100.1045'),
>   ('10.1.1.156.2724', '10.1.1.100.1045'), ('10.1.1.111.8464',
>   '10.1.1.100.1057'), ('10.1.1.105.6486', '10.1.1.100.1057'),
>   ('10.1.1.138.784', '10.1.1.100.1057'), ('10.1.1.121.2733',
>   '10.1.1.100.1057'), ('10.1.1.13.9919', '10.1.1.100.1062'),
>   ('10.1.1.12.787', '10.1.1.100.1062'), ('10.1.1.33.4425',
>   '10.1.1.100.1062'), ('10.1.1.19.1677', '10.1.1.100.1062'),
>   ('10.1.1.88.3931', '10.1.1.100.1062'), ('10.1.1.55.8054',
>   '10.1.1.100.1098'), ('10.1.1.47.3891', '10.1.1.100.1098'),
>   ('10.1.1.47.7464', '10.1.1.100.1098'), ('10.1.1.38.6745',
>   '10.1.1.100.1098'), ('10.1.1.52.168', '10.1.1.100.1098'),
>   ('10.1.1.41.1417', '10.1.1.100.1098'), ('10.1.1.116.4594',
>   '10.1.1.100.1132'), ('10.1.1.128.174', '10.1.1.100.1132'),
>   ('10.1.1.38.3827', '10.1.1.100.1153'), ('10.1.1.18.7575',
>   '10.1.1.100.1153'), ('10.1.1.56.3738', '10.1.1.100.1153'),
>   ('10.1.1.110.7560', '10.1.1.100.1153'), ('10.1.1.101.9958',
>   '10.1.1.100.1153'), ('10.1.1.28.7411', '10.1.1.100.1153'),
>   ('10.1.1.18.2975', '10.1.1.100.1153'), ('10.1.1.39.9796',
>   '10.1.1.100.1164'), ('10.1.1.104.2119', '10.1.1.100.1164'),
>   ('10.1.1.8.7906', '10.1.1.100.1164'), ('10.1.1.131.2434',
>   '10.1.1.100.1164'), ('10.1.1.78.8998', '10.1.1.100.1164'),
>   ('10.1.1.6.6222', '10.1.1.100.1164'), ('10.1.1.153.7628',
>   '10.1.1.100.1196'), ('10.1.1.100.8001', '10.1.1.100.1196'),
>   ('10.1.1.31.2802', '10.1.1.100.1196'), ('10.1.1.19.3462',
>   '10.1.1.100.1196'), ('10.1.1.128.9154', '10.1.1.100.1196')]

How do I add attributes to the Vertices created using TupleList?

Answer (score 1):

Every `Graph` has a `vs` field standing for the sequence of all vertices. This field can be manipulated as a regular Python dictionary to store attributes. You can add/set an attribute to all vertices as a whole:

```
g = Graph.TupleList([...])
g.vs['attribute'] = ['attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3', ...]
```

Or individually:

```
g.vs[0]['attribute'] = 'attr1'
```

For more info check the documentation on how to [set and retrieve attributes](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#setting-and-retrieving-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

You can add attributes directly in the tuple, using *edge_attrs* param:

```
g =  Graph.TupleList([ ('A','B',1,5),  ('A','C',2,6) , ... ],  edge_attrs=['weight','age'] )
```